Sorting numbers into bins of the same sum
I am trying to find the optimal way to sort a collection of integers into bins that all have the same sum. For simplicity we can subtract the average so we are only interested in bins that add to zero.
Take for example,
X = np.array([-2368, -2143, -1903, -1903, -1888, -1648, -1528, -1318, -1213,
              -1153, -1033,  -928,  -793,  -703,  -508,  -493,  -463,  -448,
               -418,  -358,  -223,  -118,   -88,   137,   227,   257,   347,
                347,   377,   557,   632,   632,   692,   812,   827,  1007,
               1022,  1262,  1352,  1727,  1892,  2267,  2297,  2327,  2642])

I know, there exists a way for this to form 3 groups of 15 numbers each, where each group adds to zero. But for the life of me, it is not obvious how to systematically find that solution (there could be many such solutions, I only need one).
In this smaller example, we could probably just try every combination, but if the array had a million numbers being split into 1000 bins, such an exhaustion would not work.

Is this a variation of the partition problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem, which is a known NP hard problem?

Ya, I guess, expect the restrictions are a sum of zero and an equal number of each integer being used.

I have a solution for set this small, but for the larger datasets... would be really slow.

This page on the subset sum problem states that the problem remains NP-complete even with the restriction that the sum is exactly zero. So your problem is NP-complete even if we consider additional restrictions. And (this is just my guess), the requirement that the "sum to be exactly zero" is equivalent to "allow no margin of error", which seems to make the problem harder for approximate algorithms.

The only good thing I could find is that, in your problem, the number of bins is one of the prime factors of sum(items). Note that 1000 of equal-sized bins can be merged into 500 of double-sized bins. So, while the "number of bins" may be large, the "number of candidates for the number of bins" will be surprisingly small.

Probably not exactly what you want but you can solve this problem by modeling it as an MILP with binary variables x_ib=1 iff item i is in bin b.
I obtain this result:
Bin 1 contains items: 2, 5, 6, 10, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 33, 34, 38, 39, 40, 45, 
Bin 2 contains items: 1, 7, 9, 12, 19, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 35, 36, 41, 
Bin 3 contains items: 3, 4, 8, 11, 13, 14, 15, 18, 23, 25, 30, 37, 42, 43, 44, 
Total sum: 0

Using this julia code:
using JuMP
using GLPK

function main()
    m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)

    X = [-2368, -2143, -1903, -1903, -1888, -1648, -1528, -1318, -1213,
         -1153, -1033,  -928,  -793,  -703,  -508,  -493,  -463,  -448,
         -418,  -358,  -223,  -118,   -88,   137,   227,   257,   347,
         347,   377,   557,   632,   632,   692,   812,   827,  1007,
         1022,  1262,  1352,  1727,  1892,  2267,  2297,  2327,  2642]

    n = length(X)

    @variable(m, x[1:n, 1:3], Bin) # x_i,b = 1 iff item i is in bin b

    @objective(m, Max, 0) # No need for an objective function
    @constraint(m, [i in 1:n], sum(x[i,b] for b in 1:3) == 1) # Each item is in a bin
    @constraint(m, [b in 2:3], sum(x[i,b] * X[i] for i in 1:n) == sum(x[i,1] * X[i] for i in 1:n)) # The weight of the item in bin 2 and 3 is equal to that of bin 1

    optimize!(m)

    # Display the solution
    for b in 1:3
        print("Bin ", b, " contains items: ")
        for i in 1:n
            if JuMP.value(x[i,b]) > 0.9
                print(i, ", ")
            end
        end
        println()
    end

    totalSum = 0
    for i in 1:n
        if JuMP.value(x[i,1]) > 0.9
            totalSum += X[i]
        end
    end

    println("Total sum: ", totalSum)
end 

